# Krull dimension of a $\Bbbk$-algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Given an ideal, $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq \Bbbk[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, where $\Bbbk$ is a field. Let the maximal set of indeterminates independent modulo the ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ be of cardinality $k$. Therefore the dimension of $\Bbbk[x_1,\ldots, x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ is $k$. How can we construct the chain of prime ideals in $\Bbbk[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ of length $k$?

Comment: What do you mean by "independent modulo the ideal $\mathfrak a$"?

Comment: If $S\subseteq \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ is the maximal set of indeterminates modulo $\mathfrak{a}$ then $\Bbbk[S] \cap \mathfrak{a} = \{0\}$. That is there are no elements in the ideal that are polynomials only in $S$.

Comment: One more question: how do you know that in this case $\dim\mathbb k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathfrak a=k$?

Comment: This paper here proves that using transcendence degree: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717188800452 . Does not give the chain of prime ideals though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume that $S=\{x_1,\ldots, x_k\}$. Then for any $x_m, m>k$, we have $f_m(x_1,\ldots, x_k, x_m)=0$ in $R=\mathbb{k}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$, for some non-zero polynomial $f$ in the polynomial ring. Let $a_m=a_m(x_1,\ldots, x_k)$ be the leading coefficient of $f_m$ as a polynomial in $x_m$. Let $s=\prod_{m>k} a_m$. Then, you have $\mathbb{k}[x_1,\ldots x_k]_s\subset R_s$ an integral extension and so by going up theorem, you can find a prime chain of length $k$ in $R_s$, which when pulled back to $R$ gives you such a chain in $R$.

Comment: So when we pull back to $R$ the primes remain primes?

Comment: For any ring homomorphism $A\to B$, the inverse image of a prime ideal in $B$ is a prime in $A$.

Comment: i am not very clear how $\Bbbk[x_1, \ldots,x_k]_s \subset R_s$ an integral extension. I can see that for each $x_i$s, $i \in\{1, \ldots,n\}$ there exists $f(x) \in \Bbbk[x_1, \ldots,x_k]_s [x]$ such that $f(x_i) = 0$ but how does that allow for any element $q \in R_s$ to be integral over $ \Bbbk[x_1, \ldots,x_k]_s$ ?

Comment: If $A\to B$ is a ring homomorphism,  all elements of $B$ are integral over $A$ if and only if a set of generators of $B$ as an $A$-algebra is.

Comment: should they be  a finite set of  $A$-algebra generators?

Comment: In your case, it is, but that is not necessary.

Comment: can I have a reference for this result?

Comment: Look up any book, in particular how these proofs go- say in Lang.

Comment: I know there is a chain of length $k$ in $\Bbbk[x_1, \ldots, x_k]$. But how can we be assured there is a chain of length $k$ in $\Bbbk[x_1, \ldots, x_k]_s$? Sorry for the repeated questions.

Comment: For any finitely generated $k$-domain, the length of the maximal chain of prime ideals is equal to its transcendence degree over $k$.